# Getting PasswordCredential saves

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app

In my windows universal app I'm saving some data in PasswordCredential  like this:

```
void SaveCredential(string user,string pass) 
{
    PasswordVault v = new PasswordVault();
    PasswordCredential cr = new PasswordCredential("User",user,pass);
    v.Add(cr);
}
```

and receive like:

```
IReadOnlyList<PasswordCredential> RC(string res) 
{
    PasswordVault v = new PasswordVault();
    return v.FindAllByResource(res);
}
```

when I'm trying to read PasswordCredential data I can get User info but there is no password !! it is empty ! What's the problem?

[image: Password section is empty]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Here's what the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault.findallbyresource.aspx) says:

> **Remarks**
>
> Each object returned will have the proper resource and user name, but
>   it will not include the password.

To populate the password, you need to call the [`RetrievePassword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/apps/windows.security.credentials.passwordcredential.retrievepassword.aspx) method on the `PasswordCredential` object.